# Tell ruby controller to send error message back to same web page

Tags: ruby, ajax, json, controller, render

I have a html form on my website that a user fills out. When the user clicks on the submit button I have a controller file that takes all the values from the form and uses them to insert into database. But if there was an error with their input I would like them to be redirected back to form page with an error message that would be on the screen or even redirected to another web page with same background and error message on the screen.

I have not been using ruby on rails for long so was wondering would anyone have any input into how I could do this?

Thanks in advance

Code:

```
user = User.new(:email => params[:email],
                :password => password_gen,
                :password_confirmation => password_gen,
                :name => params[:name],
                :surname => params[:surname],
                :phone => params[:phone],
                :mobile => params[:mobile])
if @user.save
  logger.debug "---------------------------"
  logger.debug user.inspect 
  logger.debug user.errors.inspect
  render :json => ["Form submitted ok for user"].to_json()
  redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User correctly created"
else
  logger.debug user.inspect
  logger.debug user.errors.inspect
  render :json => ["Error in submitting form"].to_json()
end
```

Comment: can you add your controller and view code to the question ?

Comment: Have you even tried anything, or are you hoping SO will spare you from reading the docs? :-|

Comment: I have tried render text and json but that just brings up a blank screen with the text on it. I would be happy to read how to do it if I could find the right doc but I can't find any.